# Domain Admins inherit send as permission by default

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

Domain admins inherit `send` as permission and they can send as anybody.

I want to deny `send` as permission to them. I tried to deny `send` as permission from the security tab on `mailboxes computers objects` in Active Directory and tested it, but it had no effect.

How to deny the `send` as permission for Domain Admins?

Answer (score 3):

This is the exact opposite of how a standard Exchange setup works: normally Domain Admins and Enterprise Admins are explicitly *denied* send as and receive as permission, to the point that it may be difficult to actually grant those permissions to an administrative user if required.

Something must be *very* wrong in your environment. You should have a look at the Active Directory permissions for Exchange-related objects, starting from the Organization level and digging down. You can check them using the Active Directory Sites and Services console, by enabling the option to show the Services node (usually hidden).

Comment: I agree with Massimo. This is _not_ default behaviour in a properly managed domain and properly configured Exchange organisation. @ragnar you need to figure out what has happened in order to sort this out. In the first case, I would check and see if the domain admin group has been added to one or more of the exchange administration groups. Is the exchange server installed on a domain controller by any chance? If so, then yeah - don't do that.

Comment: That wouldn't still be enough, Exchange administrators don't automatically have send as/receive as permissions *exactly* because they should be able to manage the environment but not to snoop on other people's mail. In a standard Exchange setup, nobody has global send as/receive as rights and they must always be explicitly granted to whoever needs them.

Comment: Indeed. But I'm hoping to give them a few pointers on where to start peeling back the layers of this onion. If there's any oddities at this level then it points to someone fiddling with the security of this install.

Comment: Thank You guys um gonna check and see and um gonna back to you next Thursday